# Checking if child exist not working with AngularFire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to see if a child exists. So I am creating a new Firebase list observable. I also tried with object observable. After I create the observable, I check if it exists or not. But it always ends up false.

Database Structure:

```
 {Rooms:[
    {0:
      {name:ok}
     },
     {1:
       {name:second}
      }
  ]}
```

Angular2 code:

```
isRoom(num){
 let isRoom: boolean;
 var Exists:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
 Exists=AngularFire.database.list('/Rooms/'+num);
 Exists.subscribe(snapshot =>{
   if(snapshot.exists()){
      console.log("Exists");
      isRoom=true;
   }else{
      console.log("Doesn't exists");
      isRoom=false;
    }
   return isRoom;
});
```

Comment: Please add your firebase database structure as sample.

Comment: Okay I just added the structure

Comment: Sorry it didn't look like a valid structure to me. Can you please rewrite your database structure?

Comment: Well thats how firebase organizes data. I didn't provide a key in the beginning so it starts with 0 on up.

Comment: Would you be able to just tell me what method you would use to check?

Comment: Oh I see I was missing the array part, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

The subscription to firebase is asynchronous and therefore it is still processing when the function exits.  Simply stated you can't do this this way.  You are going to need to pass in a callback function and await the return to do something like this.